# Sencha Touch 2 - Turning a Basic Account into Premium Account

Tags: touch, in-app-purchase, versioning, extjs, sencha-touch-2

Im currently developing an application through sencha touch 2 + phonegap. My question is, there should be a basic version of the application but, what if I want it to upgrade my account ? Is there a way to implement this function on sencha touch. If so, how can I do it. The thing is, if it were an android app it would automatically go to google play so you could purchase, but in this case I dont know how to do it.

Hope que question was clear enough.

Comment: what do you mean by "basic version" and "update account"? Please be more specific

Comment: I have an app with certain features and if the user wishes to have more features besides the ones they have, they should upgrade to a premium account or something. The point is, they would have to purchase/pay for that upgrade. I want to know how can I do that, what code should I implement.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you cannot create different "offline" versions of your apps such as: free edition, commercial edition with different codes and features, because in this situation, your language is Javascript.

However, if your application tends to be a web-service, you can do this using server-side authorization.

Comment: Thats exactly what it is. The concept of my app its pretty much like Dropbox. Do you think I can do that? If so, what should I do to make it work ?

Comment: I would like to know how I can sell using an in-app purchase model using Sencha Touch. What are the necessary steps required during development using Sencha Touch.

Comment: First, please do not let users purchase directly using Sencha Touch. It's unsecure. I think you can simple open a link in the user's device web browser and complete that transaction. Second, each time an user uses a feature, obviously the application has to work with server through APIs, in this process, **verify whether this is a premium user or a basic user** - leave this task to server